# Password protecting embedded firmware download

Tags: c++, c, cryptography, embedded, public-key-encryption

I need to protect against the users of our product from downloading firmware that is incompatible with the revision of the hardware that they're trying to download to. I'll describe what exists right now and what I'm looking for.

We have an alpha-numeric hardware part number and revision stored in EEPROM that is only factory programmable. When a customer attempts to download a firmware file he will have to enter a password that is distributed with the firmware release. The existing firmware needs to be able to use this password to verify that the new firmware is compatible with the current hardware revision. Keep in mind that more than one hardware revisions may be compatible with a single released version of firmware.

Is there some form of public key cryptography that can be used to validate multiple hardware revision numbers to a key that is generated during the firmware build process? The hardware revision number(s) would act as the private key while the password entered by the customer to *unlock* the download mechanism would be the public key.

The embedded firmware is written in C and it would be great if the encryption algorithm were the same. It can be C++ as long as it has an interface that lends itself to being called from C functions.

There are a couple of hardware revisions out in the wild, but we can ignore those exist for now. Let's say a brand new product is going to be released that includes this feature, so it will be revision 0.

The password will be transferred from the client's computer to the embedded hardware without any modifications. So the decryption and password matching needs to happen in the embedded firmware, which will then report success / failure back to the client. The reason for this is that it may not always be a laptop being used to download the firmware. It'll more likely be a handheld download tool so options for executing custom software are limited.

Comment: can you elaborate whether there are already several hardware revisions out there or not (in which case the design can be refined regarding security) ? does the decryption happen on the clients computer/machine and then loaded into the hardware or does the decryption happen directly in your hardware ?

Comment: @Yahia I've added additional details to the end of the question

Comment: If it is simply about protecting users against applying incorrect firmware updates, then all you need is a list in the firmware file of compatible hardware IDs, which the hardware checks before loading the firmware.  Cryptography is only needed if you are trying to stop active attempts to subvert the system - you should clarify what you are trying to protect against.

Comment: @caf Encryption is not absolutely necessary. I mentioned the cryptography thing only because I thought there might be some way to generate a single 'master' password for all supported hardware revisions which could be used by the firmware to check against its own hardware revision.

Comment: @Paretorian: In that case, I recommend keeping it simple.  I have added an answer as such.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Forget the passwords.

The simplest way to do this is to include in the firmware file, at a known location, a list of compatible hardware IDs.  This could be stored as a length-prefixed array.  When a new firmware is to be loaded into a device, the device looks for its own hardware ID in the list, and rejects the firmware if it is not present.

Such a system is robust, easy to understand and easy to debug.  If space is a concern then you can store the list as a bitset, with each hardware revision allocated a bit.

If you wish to prevent active tampering, you can further sign the entire firmware file, including the list of compatible hardware IDs, with a normal public key signature algorithm like DSA or RSA.

Comment: I like this simple solution but it has a problem. The bootloader that downloads new firmware does not buffer the entire file before burning it to flash, it simply burns whatever has been transferred, the limit being the minimum of the comm protocol limit and RAM buffer size. So it does not have the luxury of inspecting the firmware for the hardware ID list. Also, I cannot place a list that may change size at the start address of the firmware since there's other housekeeping information located in that section. At most, I can put an array pointer and number of array elements in this section.

Comment: @Praetorian: Why can't you preceed the part of the firmware that will be burned to flash with a not-burned-to-flash section that contains the list of compatible hardware IDs?  The loader starts off reading the array, checking the entries as they go then throwing that data away - then when it gets to the start of the firmware proper, it starts burning it into flash (but only if it saw a matching hardware ID in the first part of the transfer).

Comment: That is a possibility, but it means I need to write some post build script to modify the firmware hex files. I don't particularly like that part. Sorry, I'm not trying to be difficult, I should probably have listed all these limitations in the question, but I just didn't think of them at the time.

Comment: @Praetorian: Sure, but you're going to have to do some kind of processing to include the list of hardware IDs in it anyway.  Note that *any* block of data somehow identifying the valid IDs is not going to be able to beat the bitset for size.

Comment: I would use this too. No matter how you try to complicate things, you will need to send some initial data that is the identifier of the firmware to be uploaded. Call it password, id, program version or whatever, it needs to be sent _first_ before any parts of the program are sent. For the same reason you need to send an address at the beginning of any data communication, before you send the data.

Comment: (Or well, you _could_ send the whole bloody program over, let the bootloader read it without programming anything, then fish out the program version from where it is hidden in the flood of hex, then re-send the whole program once more. Very ugly and twice as slow.)

Comment: @Praetorian Wouldn't you have to modify the firmware with a post-build script if you were using encryption, too?

Comment: I use a system where the software number is sent over at the start of the file.  If it does not meet the requirements for unit compatibility then the load is rejected.  I also use a loader program on the pc (PDA/smart device) that validates the software compatibility based on rules stored in the XML format file that is used to distribute the new firmware image data.

Comment: Like Ian said, simply locate the revision number of the application being loaded to the very beginning (or at least the first packet) of data being sent to the loader.  This allows the loader to validate the version number without buffering the entire application.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't buffer the whole file before burning it?  It is good practice to validate the image (via CRC or some such) before burning it to flash.  Otherwise a glitch in communications can leave you with an unbootable processor.

Answer (score 1):

So we assume this is a fresh design:

I am not really how much security you want/need and how processing power your device has...

I would make the firmware package consist of two parts - a header and the "real thing".
Both should be encrypted differently and then signed independently plus together  (this is the public key cryptography part).

- first check the outer signature
- then check the signature of header (which must be calculated based on the header, header length plus the password)
- The header is encrypted with the password you distribute and contains a list of hashes of the compatible hardware revisions (these hashes are calculated from the hardware revision + password).
  The device decrypts the header, hashes its own revision from the EEPROM accordingly (again revision + password) and tries to find a match in the list.
  IF it finds a match then it takes the hash of the list in the header.
- with the hash of the list it check the signature of the the "real thing" (calculated on the encrypted content plus length plus password plus hash of the list)
- if the signature is valid it proceeds decrypting the "real thing" (key would be password + hash of list)

For the signature part you create a cert, sign that cert with your root cert... the derived cert would be embedded into the devices... so you create the signatures with the private key of that cert and check them in the device with the public key.

The above is NOT 100% secure but provides several aspects:

- tampering with package would be always detectable (as long as you don't loose your private key that is)
- it won't be installable on any incompatible hardware revision
- figuring out the scheme wouldn't allow for installation on incompatble hardware revisions (except if your customer somehow modifies your hardware)

IF that is two much calculations etc. you could always simplify the scheme... at the bare minimum I would keep the outer signature and the password...

---

EDIT - after some discussion (see comments):

The base algorithms to create the "password" I suggest consists of 2 parts - a hashing algorithm and an encryption algorithm:

- hashing algorithm
  The respective firmware should be hashed ("good" algorithms are SHA-512, SHA-384, SHA-256, MD5 - "VERY WEAK" algorithm would be CRC32)
- encryption algorithm
  The password would be encrypted using either an asymetric algorithm (like RSA, EC etc.) or a symetric algorithm ("strong" ones are AES, Blowfisch etc. - "weak" ones are for example DES - "VERY WEAK" is for example XOR)

The scheme consists of the following steps:

- hash the firmware with any of the above hashing algorithms
- build a string consisting of part number/ revision number + firmware hash
- encrypt the string with any of the above mentioned encryption algorithms (asymetric means you use the private key, symetric means you use the same key for encryption/decryption)

The device need to contain a secret key (which is either the public key if asymetric encryption is used or the key in case of symetric encryption) and the part number/revision number.

Checking the firmware against the password means decrypting the password, hashing the firmware and comparing the part number/revision number and firmware hash...

Security aspects versus processing requirements:

- asymetric encryption means handling big number (1024 bit or bigger)
  IF the device is not capable of handling that you should perhaps take a symetric encryption.
- symetric encryption means that IF your customer reads out the key from your hardware he would be able to create "valid passwords" himself while in the asymetric case this won't be possible
- you could stick with hashing only (hash the firmware plus part numerb/revision number) and provide the result as a password but this leaves you open to a customer figuring the algorithm used out and then they can create themselves "valid passwords"

Some relevant links:

- http://www.cryptosys.net/
- http://www.openssl.org/
- http://www.cryptopp.com/
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric-key_algorithm

Comment: +1 That would work but it is very complicated. I don't think I need to encrypt the firmware itself. Ideally, all I need to generate is a byte array (password) that can be *mapped* (I know that's incorrect terminology) to all the part number + revision numbers that that build supports. Is there any way of doing that? Also, I don't know much about cryptography, so if you could suggest names of algorithms I can use for this I could at least try to find implementations in C.

Comment: ok - that can be simplified alot then... your requirement to have a password (byte array) containing somehow all allowed part numbers/revisions is possible, the problem arrises when the device want to check compatibility - it would either need to decrypt the byte array and then check against the list (this could the byte array very long) OR it would need to know the exact combination of partnumbers/revisions used to generate the byte array

Comment: what password length is ok ? or would be ok to deliver the same firmware with different password (one for each sompatible partnumber/revision ?

Comment: The password can be several hundred bytes if needed, but are you saying the length keeps increasing as we add more supported part numbers? It may be acceptable to release different passwords for compatible revision numbers, but not ideal. So there's no way to generate a 'master' password of fixed length that can then somehow be used by the embedded firmware to figure out that the hardware is compatible?

Comment: I don't see how such a master password would work except with an increasing length with every added compatible partnumber/revision

Comment: should I list some algorithms (perhaps with links) to create such partnumber/revision specific password ? you could lessen the burden IF you can "group the compatible parts" somehow (i.e. divide the partnumber/revision into a part which is used for the password and another part i.e. sub-revision or so which is not used in the password check...

Comment: Yes please, thanks for all your help. It is very much possible to compress the part number + revision into some format where only the additional revision numbers can be listed again if that's all that has changed.